# Select range equal to variables in array using loop

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

[image]

I wrote a program using VBA which shown below. there was an array(ary) which contain(C,F,B,PC,PB). I create the loop to go through each variable in the array.

what I want to do with my code is I have a datasheet that includes that array values as categories. I want to assign each array values to **p** range. then execute data from the p range. then want to assign p to next array value and do the same.

but the problem is range p is firstly set ary(1)="C" and give the correct result. but after it becomes equal to "F" didn't work properly. it contains the same range previously gave. can anyone help me with this problem?

```
For i = 1 To UBound(ary)
cat = ary(i)
Set p = Nothing
Set c = Nothing
    For Each c In Range("E:E")
        If c.Value = cat Then
            If p Is Nothing Then
                Set p = c.Offset
        Else
            Set p = Union(p, c)
        End If
    End If
Next c

'get values
p.Offset(, -1).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

next i
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do with your code ?

Comment: `Set p = c.Offset` you cannot use offset like this you need to tell how many rows and columns you want to offset `c.Offset(rows, columns)` otherwise it doesn't make sense. Or did you mean `Set p = c`? • Can you be more detailed than *"didn't work properly"*? Please try to give some good example data for input and desired output or a screenshot. See [mcve].

Comment: There was an array named as ary() and there were 5 categories include this array which is (C,F,B,PC,PB) and I have datasheet including these categories. I want to get ranges first which equals "C" then equal to"F" like a vise. but the problem is when I run the program in the first time in loop p assign to range which are including "C" but then it becomes i=2(which mean cat=F) then it again gives range p same result previously gave.

Comment: What do you mean by *"then execute data from the p range"*? • Please share data examples or a screenshot.

Comment: I have 2 data columns placed in D & E. in the D column have dates and E column contain category ID. which are mentioned in my array as ary(C, F, B, PC, PB). which I want to mean get dates(which are in column D) equal to each category separately. therefore I assigned p as a variable range and create a loop. in my code, I commented get values in the bottom. that code I used to get data. but this code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The key error in your code is the idea that you might collect a range of non-consecutive cells and paste their value into a contiguous range. Excel can't do that. My code below collects qualifying values into an array and pastes that array into the target range.

The code below can't be exactly what you want because you didn't provide some vital information. However, please try it anyway with the aim of adapting it to your project.

```
Private Sub Review()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' last row in column E
    Dim Ary() As String
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Ary = Split("C,F,B,PC,PB", ",")             ' this array would be 0-based
    Rl = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row   ' Range("E:E") has 1.4 million cells
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, "E"), Cells(Rl, "E"))

    For i = 0 To UBound(Ary)
        ReDim Arr(1 To Rl)
        n = 0
        For Each Cell In Rng
            If Cell.Value = Ary(i) Then
                n = n + 1
                Arr(n) = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
        Next Cell

        If n Then
            ReDim Preserve Arr(n)
            'get values
            Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Offset(1) _
                    .Resize(UBound(Arr)).Value = Arr ' Application.Transpose(Arr)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This code works entirely on the `ActiveSheet` and then pastes the result to another sheet, named as "Sheet1". That isn't good practice. The better way would be to declare variables for both sheets and let the code refer to the variables so as to ensure that it has full control of which sheet it's working on at all times.

Comment: Hi in my code I want to assign a range to early defined p (as a range). then this p I used to get values to equal categories in an array. from using the below code.

p.Offset(, -1).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

I want to assign p to ranges which are included categories in ary() . can I do that from this code?

Comment: *"collect a range of non-consecutive cells and paste their value into a contiguous range."* That's not true, Excel **can** do that as long as all non-consecutive cells are either in one row or in one column. What Excel actually cannot do is `p.Offset(, -1)` if `p` consists of non-consecutive cells, but to get around this issue you could `.Offset(, -1)` *before* collecting them with `union()`.

Comment: If you want to assign a range to another range `p` my code doesn't do that. If you want to collect matching values from a source controlled by matches in column E and paste those values in column N of your worksheet Ws, that's a description of what my code does. I took the time to write the code for you, I think it's fair for you to take the time to look at it.

Comment: @AkilaDissanayake, other than fair to Variatus, it'd be useful for all we readers to know form you

Answer (score -2):

`Set p = Union(p, c)` will never be executed because it will only occur if p is NOT nothing, and  `Set p = Nothing` is executed each time the outer loop iterates.

Comment: That is not correct because there is another (inner) loop `For Each c In Range("E:E")` where `p` is set if it was nothing `Set p = c.Offset`. So in this loop it is possible that `p` is `Nothing` then it is set to something and afterwards (in the next iteration of that inner loop) `Set p = Union(p, c)` will be executed.